# How to remove straight lines from a Matlab image?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-figure

I have a matlab image from a matrix named [**`Two_dim`**](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=04371474922222971816) as shown in the figure below.

I would like to remove all 3 of the *bottom straight horizontal lines* from the image. I looked up on Stackoverflow to use `regionprops` to eliminate horizontal lines and obtained this code. But that doesn't seem to remove the lines.

```
rp = regionprops(Two_dim, 'PixelIdxList', 'Eccentricity', 'Orientation');
rp = rp([rp.Eccentricity]>0.95 & (abs([rp.Orientation])<2 | abs([rp.Orientation])>89));
Two_dim(vertcat(rp.PixelIdxList)) = false;
```

[image: Noisy Image]

Comment: You need to check how you define a line, is it one pixel width and if it has no pixel break?

Comment: Yes. If there is a pixel break, that is not a problem. There are some noisy pixels which are horizontal as well. I want to remove all the bottom horizontal things (even if small).

Comment: I'm not sure that `regionprops` is the best method for this. You might want to check [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/detect-lines-using-the-radon-transform.html) and [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/hough-transform.html)

Comment: I'll try this. I want to totally remove the lines. Is removing possible through Hough transform?

Comment: These methods are for detecting the lines, choose whatever works best for you. After that step, you can remove them manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an answer using Hough transform approach. I will add some more explanations to the code below later:

```
% I crop only the intresting part for illustration:
BW = edge(Two_dim(1:1000,:),'canny');
subplot 131
imagesc(Two_dim(1:1000,:))
title('Original image')
axis xy
[H,theta,rho] = hough(BW); % preform Hough transform
subplot 132
P = houghpeaks(H,10,'NHoodSize',[1 1]); % find the peaks in the transformation
lines_found = houghlines(BW,theta,rho,P,...
    'FillGap',50,'MinLength',1); % convert the peaks to line objects
imagesc(Two_dim(1:1000,:)), hold on
result = Two_dim(1:1000,:);
for k = 1:length(lines_found)
   % extract one line:
   xy = [lines_found(k).point1; lines_found(k).point2];
   % Plot the detected lines:
   plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',1,'Color','green');
   % remove the lines from the image:
   % note that I take a buffer of 3 to the 'width' of the line
   result(xy(1,2):xy(1,2)+3,xy(1,1):xy(2,1)) = 0;
end
title('Detected lines')
axis xy
subplot 133
imagesc(result)
title('Corrected image')
axis xy
```

The output:

[image: find a line]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation sir! Your answers have always helped me. However in the corrected image (last figure), I'm still getting the line at row 198. Am I doing anything wrong.?

Comment: And I also want to understand and know about the different parameters like how number 10 is taken in houghpeaks and how the result is taken as xy(1:2):xy(1:2)... etc as I'm not very much familiär with Hough transform.

Comment: I'll try to explain later more about it. But meanwhile, for your case [`'FillGap'` and `'MinLength'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghlines.html?s_tid=doc_ta#namevaluepairs) are the most important. Try to play with them a little.

Comment: I got it. I changed xy(1,2) to xy(1,1). in the first element of the result. Thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

You could look at the row intensity sums. They will stand out as long as the lines stay horizontal.

```
grayI = rgb2gray(I);

rowSums = sum(grayI,2);

plot(rowSums);
```

[image: Plot of row sums]

```
filterRows = rowSums > 1*10^5

I(filterRows,:,:) = 255;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this method as well. Very much useful

Answer (score 0):

`regionprops` needs a binary image with each pixel being one of two values.

You can do e.g.

```
Two_dim(Two_dim<0.5) = 0;
Two_dim(Two_dim>=0.5) = 1; # the actual value doesn't matter
```

or

```
Two_dim = logical(Two_dim);
```

Comment: I tried this. It removed some of the lines but not everything. The line at row 198 for example in the above image and the one below it still remains.

Comment: Ok. I agree with EBH that `regionprops` is probably not the best solution. As soon as the objects join with something else (as does the middle line in row 198) the properties of the BLOB change completely.